# Why wildcard cannot stand for directory in FindFirstFile?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to use `FindFirstFile` to check if some files exist following a pattern, but it appears that the wildcard `*` cannot stand for a directory.

```
int main()
{
  WIN32_FIND_DATAW findFileData;
  wchar_t path[] = LR"(.\*\*.txt)";
  HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(path, &findFileData);

  if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    do
    {
      printf("%S\n", findFileData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &findFileData));
  }
}
```

With this tree, nothing is printed:

```
.
|- foo
|  |- some.txt
|
|- bar
|  |- another.txt
```

Why this limitation? Does a workaround exist?

Comment: Because `*\*\*` is not valid directory name. If you want to search folder hierarchy for some files, you have to implement recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wild cards are only permitted in the part of the file name after the final path separator. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) does explain this. It says:

> The directory or path, and the file name. The file name can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?).

If you want to search through multiple directories you will need to implement that nested or recursive iteration explicitly.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did not understand there were a formal distinction between path and file name. I run under Debian at home, and AFAIK there is no such distinction: in the shell, you can put a wildcard wherever you want.

Comment: @Boiethios you cannot compare the shell's wildcards handling with a system calls wildcard handling. The Linux equivalent (`opendir` and `readdir` I think) of `FindFirstFile` doesn't do what the shell does.

Comment: Yes, `opendir()` and `readdir()` are the equivalents of `FindFirstFile("*.*")` (specifically; anything more complex requires you to do the pattern matching), and yes, they will not cross directory boundaries. Unix libc provides a function `ftw()` that will do a recursive walk; not sure if msvcrt does too... And even then you'd still have to do pattern matching yourself.

Comment: @Boiethios The globbing that you are talking about is implemented in the shell, it's not a service offered by the system, as I understand it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan glob http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html is not a shell implementation, it is POSIX.

Comment: @Boiethios OK, I did not know that

Comment: However, on POSIX systems it's the shell that does glob expansion; programs don't do it themselves. On Windows it's not so clear as far as I can tell (does `CommandLineToArgvW()` do it?). The difference is not that the `glob()` function exists, it's who calls it.

Comment: @andlabs Certainly the `cmd` shell doesn't do glob expansion. I'd imagine that ports of bash that run on Windows would.

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> The *file name* can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?).

So only the last part can have a wildcard, previous parts have to be explicit.

You have to implement the functionality you want in two parts: first list all directories and then list all files from them with the wildcard.